# How to read long numbers from file to vector<int>?

Tags: c++

I need to read a file where two first lines are huge numbers (up to 200 digits):

```
1. 123456789123456789...
2. 123456789123456789...
```

and put both of them into:

```
std::vector<int> digits[2];
```

How to do that?

Reading file to `std::string` like that:

```
std::string line[2];

void input(char* filename)
{
    std::fstream inFile;
    inFile.open(filename, std::ios::in);
    if(inFile.is_open())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            std::getline(inFile, line[i]);
        }
    }

    inFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Please, explain better what should be stored in each element of the vector; e.g., a single digit, four digits, maximal possible integer etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
std::vector<int> digits[2];

void input(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream inFile(filename);
    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            std::string header, number;
            inFile >> header >> number;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < number.size(); ++j)
                digits[i].push_back(number[j] - '0');
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem particularly difficult. I have made a couple of assumptions because your requirements aren't completely clear.

In my code `header` gets the '1.' or '2.' part at the beginning of the line which I'm assuming you aren't interested in. After that it's just a matter of looping through the `number` string and converting each digit to it's integer value (which is what I'm assuming you want to do) and adding it to the vector. You convert a digit to it's integer value by subtracting `'0'`, as you can see in the code above.

Comment: Could you please answer what is '0'?

Comment: '0' is the character zero. By subtracting '0' from the character in the string you convert the character to it's integer value, so you convert '0' to 0, '1' to 1, '2' to 2, etc. I've assumed that this is what you want to do, but if it isn't then change or get rid of it.

Comment: @ErliMoen I've guessing that you are not familiar with C++ *types*. In C++ everything has a type. That could be `int` or `char` or `std::string` or something else. `'0'` is a `char`, `0` is an `int`, the two aren't the same, and `std::string` is a sequence of `char`, so you need to convert those `char`s to `int`s which is what my code does.